# How can I write on Arduino from PC with rs-485 and QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, rs485

I have linked my PC and my Arduino with a RS-485 line and a TTL/RS-485 converter. I receive the message from Arduino but when I want to send information from my PC, there is no receipt on Arduino.
My Arduino code is :

```
const int slavePin = 4 // link to RE and DE of converter module.

void setup(){
   pinMode(slavePin, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(slavePin, LOW);
}
c
void loop{
   while(Serial.available()){
      if(Serial.Read()){
         digitalWrite(2, HIGH); // switch on a led.
      } 
   }
}
```

In my C++ code i have all initialization parameter. I don't forget write in `arduino->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);` line.
 My function for write to arduino is call when i clicked on button.

```
void Dialog::serialWrite(){
   quint8 bw = 0;
   serialDataWrite = "1";
   if(arduino !=NULL && arduino->isWritable()){   // arduino is my QSerialPort object.
      bw = arduino->write(serialDataWrite);
      qDebug() << bw << "bytes written | Value sent : " << serialDataWrite;
   }
}
```

This function work when I use the rs-232 link but not with rs-485. Someone can help me ?

Comment: RS232 and RS485 have a different architecture do you using a RS232 to RS485 converter? It might be a physical problem not a software problem.

Comment: There is a physical difference but normally i can use the same software. My function read run with rs-232 and rs485 without issues.

Comment: Is change in case for serialDataWrite in  ` SerialDataWrite = "1";` and `arduino->write(serialDataWrite);` a typo?

Comment: Yes you can use the same software. I said that because if it works with RS232 you should check other part of system. Test with other communicating software to make sure of your physical line. Like hercules in windows or putty on linux.

Comment: Bad typo here but in my code it is good. i had edit for change this error. I will test putty and come back for say if it works.

Comment: I read the Arduino message but can i write with putty ?

Comment: On the PC, side some RS485 transceivers have their transmit-enable auto-activated when you transmit. Others, however, require that you manually active the transmitter, usually by taking manual control of DTR in your code. You might use a scope or analyzer or cleverly designed Arduino code  to see if your attempt to write from the PC is even causing the A,B lines to toggle at all. If not, it may be that you need manual control of DTR. If you have two of these adapters, you might connect them together and back to the PC and just test with terminals and your software. Update with findings.